# Unable to add database in Apache Superset 0.24

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, apache-superset

I am trying to add MSSql database to Superset. here is the python script used to generate SQLAlchemy Url -

```
urllib.quote_plus('DRIVER={%s};Server=%s;Database=%s;UID=;PWD=;ServerSPN=%s'
                       %(DB_DRIVER,DB_SERVER,DB_NAME,DB_SERVER_SPN))
```

Then I go to Sources>Databases>add option in Superset and provide SQLAlchemy URI and click "Test Connection" which gives me all ok! , Then I click "Save" button and i get below exception.

(pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Easysoft][SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]General error: server name not specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)

Comment: If you log the output of your script, does it follow this convention?: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Thanks! i followed the Url and it worked.